# NetSuite Web Services, SuiteTalk 2014.1, customerSearchAdvanced brings back wrong data for parentRef

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, rest, netsuite

I am attempting to complete a NetSuite Web Services, SuiteTalk (2014.1), call that uses the customerSearchAdvance option to retrieve a customer (in order to save time and data).  However when compared to a customerSearchBasic the parentRef of the customer that is returned is returning different data.

Take the current situation for example.

**Customer #1**
Name: Smith Inc.
Internal ID: 1049
Parent: NONE

**Customer #2**
Name: Smith East
Internal ID: 1290
Parent: Smith Inc. (1049)

**Customer #3**
Name: South East
Internal ID: 1427
Parent: Smith East (1290)

On a **customerSearchBasic** I get the following information back in the parent (recordRef) Object, which we will call parentRef, when search for internalId 1427 (South East).
**parentRef.internalId** = 1290
**parentRef.name** = "Smith Inc. : South East"

On a **customerSearchAdvanced** I get the following information back in the parent (recordRef) Object, which we will call parentRef, when search for internalId 1427 (South East).
**parentRef.internalId** = 1049
**parentRef.name** = NULL

My question here is, why am I getting the highest level parent on the Advanced search and not the next higher.  And is there some setting that I may be missing.  I am including the parent column as a search column in the advanced search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetSuite has confirmed that this is a bug and a defect has been filed with NetSuite.

Once the defect has been fixed I will try and remember to update this issue.

Sorry to everyone else out there who has also ran into the same problem.